# Deploy browser with addons and settings [Chrome/Edge]

Tags: google-chrome, browser, extension

How can I copy and set up a browser on a new computer [either me or a family member] with all my extensions installed?

Whether its from a usb stick or sending a file, doesnt matter. Im looking for ease of deployment with all my settings.

extension examples include: ublock, onenote clipper, privacy badger to name a few.

Also, let me know if i need to clarify the question with more info.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015?hl=en) help?  You will have to be more specific on one step of the process you are stuck on.  In it's current state your question is far to broad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.